# Does placing ng-template inside *ngFor affect performance at all?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular-template

Let's assume following ItemComponent that is created many times:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items">
    <app-item [data]="item"></app-item>
</li>
```

and contains buttons that on click display some complex modal dialogs .

Does it affect performance of the app (e.g. startup time, or memory footprint), when I place some ng-templates of the dialogs inside the ItemComponent, or outside the *ngFor?

I mean, I know the templates are not instantiated until the dialogs are invoked, but I'm not sure if the template itself is created once per component, or once per instance?

Comment: all ItemComponents will still be available in the dom so i don't see a reason why using ng-template will affect performance

Answer (score 2):

> Does it affect performance of the app (e.g. startup time, or memory footprint), when I place some ng-templates of the dialogs inside the ItemComponent, or outside the *ngFor?

`<ng-template>` is a component that will be created. The component creates a template reference from it's inner DOM elements, and those DOM elements are not rendered on the page. The template remains in memory for each `item` created in the `ngFor`. *ngTemplate* has a current *context* and an injected *context*. The value of `item` will be present in the current context when it is inside `ngFor` and must be provided in the context object when using `ngTemplateOutlet`.

It is a better practice to keep `ngTemplate` outside of `ngFor` and pass `item` as part of the context when using `ngTemplateOutlet`.

Here's a tutorial that helps explain things better.

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

Comment: I'm still not 100% convinced :) Technically, I see no reason why `ng-template` should be in memory for each item. The current and injected context could be applied just when the template is instantiated and the result would be the same. The blog post is good, but not related to this